# JPA support for Java 8 new date and time API

Tags: java, jpa, java-8, jpa-2.1, java-time

I'm using Java 8 for my new project.

I'm trying to use new date and time api in java 8 however I don't know if `JPA 2.1` fully supports this new Date and Time API or not.

Please share your experience/opinion in JPA`s supports for new date and time API in Java 8.

**Can I use new date and time api in Java 8 safely with JPA 2.1?**

**UPDATE:**

I'm using Hibernate (4.3.5.Final) as JPA implementation.

Comment: Have a look at this : http://javajeedevelopment.blogspot.fr/2016/11/datetime-jpahibernate-mapping.html

Comment: This is the principal reason -not- to use Java reference types for temporal data in the database layer.  If the database format for date-times is a numeric format, such as a Modified Julian Day number (can hold a date-time to millisecond precision in a double), there is never a problem with ORM support.  Moreover, the Converter facility that is part of JPA 2.1 makes interconversion between numeric formats and objects in the time library of your choosing super easy.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

JPA 2.1 is a spec that came out before Java 1.8, so doesn't mandate any support for it. Obviously some implementations may support some Java 1.8 features. Some have problems with Java 1.8 bytecode (e.g EclipseLink). I know DataNucleus supports java.time and Java 1.8 since that's the one I use. You'd have to check your implementation for what its support level is.

It has been requested that JPA 2.2 support the java.time types, see this issue https://java.net/jira/browse/JPA_SPEC-63

Comment: Thanks. I'm using Hibernate as JPA implementation as in updated question.

Comment: Anyone can search for Hibernate support for such things. You find this https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8844  so no, your selected JPA implementation doesn't support it

Comment: EclipseLink has no longer any problem with Java 8 bytecode.

Comment: @eskatos, what is the version number of the release of EclipseLink that is fixed? I don't see a release since 26-Sep-2013 (v2.5.1) and none is present in Maven Central.

Comment: @NeilStockton I use the 2.5.1 release with Java 8 without any issue. That is `org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:2.5.1`.

Comment: Oh, my bad, EclipseLink 2.5.1 fails if a lambda expression is present in an entity class. Not the case for me, that's why everything work has expected. See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=429992

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 73):

For Hibernate 5.X just add

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

and

```
@NotNull
@Column(name = "date_time", nullable = false)
protected LocalDateTime dateTime;
```

will work without any additional effort.
See https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8844

UPDATE:

Please have a look at Jeff Morin comment: since Hibernate 5.2.x it is enough

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
     <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-...</artifactId>
     <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```

See https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/wiki/Migration-Guide---5.2 and
[Integrate Hibernate 5.2 with Spring framework 4.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37651837/integrate-hibernate-5-2-with-spring-framework-4-x)

Comment: Starting with Hibernate 5.2.x this addition is not necessary anymore since these Java 8 features were merged into Hibernate Core.

Comment: Thanks! Together with migration to Spring 4.3.x (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37651837/integrate-hibernate-5-2-with-spring-framework-4-x) works!

Comment: While I don't understand, what would happen if hibernate does not support new date api? Now for LocalDateTime columns they are stored as blob type in mysql, do you think this is the right behavior?

Answer (score 13):

## JPA 2.2 supports java.time

**JPA 2.2** now supports `LocalDate`, `LocalTime`, `LocalDateTime`, `OffsetTime` and `OffsetDateTime`.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

For JPA 2.2 implementation, **Hibernate 5.2** or **EclipseLink 2.7** can be used.

Hibernate 5 supports more java types than JPA 2.2 like `Duration`, `Instant` and `ZonedDateTime`.

More Info:

- [How To Map The Date And Time API with JPA 2.2](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/map-date-time-api-jpa-2-2/) by Thorben Janssen
- [What’s new in JPA 2.2](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/whats-new-in-jpa-2-2/)
- [JSR 338 (Maintenance Release)](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr338/index.html)
- [JPA 2.2 Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API#JPA_2.2)

Answer (score 9):

I am using Java 8, EclipseLink(JPA 2.1), PostgreSQL 9.3 and PostgreSQL Driver -Postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar in my project and I can use `LocalDateTime` variables from the new API with no error, but the data type of the column will be bytea in the database. You can only read it from a Java application as far i know.

However, you can use `AttributeConverter` to convert these classes to `java.sql.Date`. I found this code from [Java.net](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/montanajava/archive/2014/06/17/using-java-8-datetime-classes-jpa)

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDatePersistenceConverter implements
AttributeConverter {
@Override
public java.sql.Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate entityValue) {
    return java.sql.Date.valueOf(entityValue);
}

@Override
public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(java.sql.Date databaseValue) {
    return databaseValue.toLocalDate();
}
```

Comment: You can use user-type for mapping. See this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/jpa%2Fjava8%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fexample%2Fspringdata%2Fjpa%2Fjava8%2FAbstractEntity.java

Comment: "with no problem but the data type of the column is bytea in the database" ... there is a problem from the start. A date/time should not be serialised!

Comment: it doesn´t if you use the converters to java.sql as i pointed. Sorry if i be unclear

Answer (score 9):

[org.jadira.usertype](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jadira.usertype/usertype.core) can be used to persist JSR 310 Date and Time API.

Check out this [example project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/jpa%2Fjava8%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fexample%2Fspringdata%2Fjpa%2Fjava8%2FAbstractEntity.java).

From Example Project,

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class AbstractEntity {

    @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;

    @CreatedDate//
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.threeten.PersistentZonedDateTime")//
    ZonedDateTime createdDate;

    @LastModifiedDate//
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.threeten.PersistentZonedDateTime")//
    ZonedDateTime modifiedDate;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure but I think it should work with Eclipselink also. Try it out.

Comment: The link to example project now uses some Spring specific annotation. Here is the link to older commit of this same project: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/e953f6d5e5725bce65430d160e430f042c16a8c3/jpa/java8/src/main/java/example/springdata/jpa/java8/AbstractEntity.java (my edit request has been rejected)

Answer (score 3):

I know that this is an old question but I thought of an alternative solution which might be helpful.

Instead of trying to map the new java.time.* classes to an existing database types, you can leverage @Transient:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    private Long id;        
    private Timestamp createdTimestamp;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() { return id; }

    private Timestamp getCreatedTimestamp() {
        return createdTime;
    }

    private void setCreatedTimestamp(final Timestamp ts) {
        this.createdTimestamp = ts;
    }

    @Transient
    public LocalDateTime getCreatedDateTime() {
        return createdTime.getLocalDateTime();
    }

    public void setCreatedDateTime(final LocalDateTime dt) {
        this.createdTime = Timestamp.valueOf(dt);
    }
}
```

You work with the public getter/setter methods that use the new Java 8 date/time classes, but behind the scenes the getter/setters work with the legacy date/time classes. When you persist the entity, the legacy date/time property will be persisted but not the new Java 8 property since it's annotated with @Transient.

Comment: you forgot to declare the LocalDateTime createdTime variable in the code.

Comment: and also private getter/setter for persistent fields (the Timestamp) are not allowed in JPA specification it must be at least Protected but some JPA implementations ignore it and it works but not the standard

Answer (score 1):

For type **TIMESTAMP** you can use this converter:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateTimeAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDateTime, Timestamp> {

    @Override
    public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDateTime datetime) {
        return datetime == null ? null : Timestamp.valueOf(datetime);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Timestamp timestamp) {
        return timestamp == null ? null : timestamp.toLocalDateTime();
    }

}
```

For type **DATE** you can use this converter:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date> {

    @Override
    public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate date) {
        return date == null ? null : Date.valueOf(date);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(Date date) {
        return date == null ? null : date.toLocalDate();
    }

}
```

For type **TIME** you can use this converter:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalTimeAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalTime, Time> {

    @Override
    public Time convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalTime time) {
        return time == null ? null : Time.valueOf(time);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalTime convertToEntityAttribute(Time time) {
        return time == null ? null : time.toLocalTime();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are Many approach to do , Also It depends to your frame work :
If your frame work has on field Converter such spring do such:
1-

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy - HH:mm")
private Long createdDate;
```

here I am using legacy epoch format https://www.epochconverter.com/
epoch is very flexible and accepted format

2- The other ways is to use jpa   @PostLoad  @PreUpdate    @PrePersist

```
@PostLoad
      public void convert() {
        this.jva8Date= LocalDate.now().plusDays(1);
      }
```

or use temp one such

```
@Transient
public LocalDateTime getCreatedDateTime() {
    return createdTime.getLocalDateTime();
}
```