# What MySQL type to use for java.time.ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jodatime, java-time

1) How many columns do I need in MySQL database to store **java.time.ZonedDateTime**?

2) **DATETIME vs TIMESTAMP** MySQL types - what is better to store ZonedDateTime and LocalDateTime

Based on this [article](http://www.joda.org/joda-time-hibernate/userguide.html) PersistentDateTimeTZ is used to store joda DateTime in 2 columns. So I expect to have the same for  But when I try to use

```
@Columns(columns={@Column(name="transaction_date"),@Column(name="transaction_date_tz")})
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.threeten.PersistentZonedDateTime")
    private ZonedDateTime transactionDate;
```

I get exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: property mapping has wrong number of columns: my.package.Transaction.transactionDate type: org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.threeten.PersistentZonedDateTime
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270)
```

P.S.

hibernate-version 4.2.7.Final

jadira-version 4.0.0.GA

Comment: Try TheKojuEffect's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718383/jpa-support-for-java-8-new-date-and-time-api

Comment: I saw this article before posting my question. It does not answer question what database column bype and columns number to use

Answer (score -2):

It's a tinyblob. Just got it working with Grails3.

Comment: BLOBs won´t allow ordering so this is highly unefficient