# JPA Console in Intellij with JHipster-generated Spring-boot project

Tags: jpa, intellij-idea, spring-boot, jhipster

Is it possible to setup Persistence tab and JPA console in Intellij IDEA with annotation-based Spring-boot project, generated with JHipster (to test JPA queries etc.)? 
Any clues and any experience will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to setup this feature with IDEA 2017+
The only problem was the SQL generation issue which was resolved with this workaround:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-216295

Answer (score 0):

I'm using jhipster generator and the following worked for me

Define a persistence.xml file with your database configuration (name doesnt matter)
you can copy a sample form here https://gist.github.com/rafaeltuelho/fb7fc0d372a0cf85a53e

Then the in Persistence tab you should be able to see this configuration and open de JPA console. I tried do a simple count query and it works,

```
select count(u) from User u
```

Also if I place attributes it works

```
select u.firstName, u.lastName from User u
```

But when i want to query all user object it fails, with

```
StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 32303136
```

I'm not 100% sure but seems the issue is related with ZonedDateTime. This question is related
[JPA support for Java 8 new date and time API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718383/jpa-support-for-java-8-new-date-and-time-api)