# Integrate Hibernate 5.2 with Spring framework 4.x

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using latest stable Spring version (`4.2.6.RELEASE`).

After upgrading Hibernate from 5.1 to 5.2 and changing `hibernate-entitymanager` dependency to `hibernate-core` due hibernate documentation: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/wiki/Migration-Guide---5.2

I dont receive any compile error but all my tests fails with this stack trace:

```
Jun 06, 2016 12:00:38 PM org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager beforeTestMethod
WARNING: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@548b7f67] to process 'before' execution of test method [public void com.rh.cores.architecture.tests.units.person.PersonTest.add_iranianNaturalPersonDateIsInvalid_preventSaving()] for test instance [com.rh.cores.architecture.tests.units.person.PersonTest@7f9e8421]
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.getFlushMode()Lorg/hibernate/FlushMode;
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:431)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionContext.startTransaction(TransactionContext.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:200)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:265)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.getFlushMode()Lorg/hibernate/FlushMode;
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.prepareFlushMode(HibernateJpaDialect.java:187)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:173)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380)
    ... 30 more

Jun 06, 2016 12:00:38 PM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils executeSqlScript
INFO: Executing SQL script from class path resource [test/downs/architecture/down.sql]
Jun 06, 2016 12:00:38 PM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils executeSqlScript
INFO: Executed SQL script from class path resource [test/downs/architecture/down.sql] in 5 ms.

org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.getFlushMode()Lorg/hibernate/FlushMode;

    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:431)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionContext.startTransaction(TransactionContext.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:200)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:265)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.getFlushMode()Lorg/hibernate/FlushMode;
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.prepareFlushMode(HibernateJpaDialect.java:187)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:173)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380)
    ... 30 more
```

Comment: Spring framework 4.3.0.RC2 is available which supports Hibernate 5.2. This is RC version, but GA will be available soon.You can upgrade spring but then need to track and update whenever the GA is available

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`Hibernate 5.2` supports added in `Spring framework 4.3` , that its stable version will be available in next week.
Spring 4.2 only supports Hibernate up to 5.1.

see this:

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14334

Answer (score 3):

The issue is related to the versions only. 
Use Hibernate version 5.1.0 with Spring 4.3.7. It will solve this issue.
Add the below dependency along with Spring framework dependencies of version 4.3.x .

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>`
```

Answer (score -4):

methods are

**applyFlushModeHint**

```
protected boolean applyFlushModeHint(FlushMode flushMode)

Apply the FlushMode hint.

Parameters:
    flushMode - The FlushMode value specified as hint
Returns:
    true if the hint was "applied"
```

Where FlushMode can be

**ALWAYS** The Session is flushed before every query.
**AUTO**   The Session is sometimes flushed before query execution in order to ensure that queries never return stale state.
**COMMIT** The Session is flushed when Transaction.commit() is called.
**MANUAL** The Session is only ever flushed when Session.flush() is explicitly called by the application.
**NEVER**  Deprecated. use MANUAL instead.

Comment: I don't  use this method directly. it called by Spring transaction manager! Is this means that I should wait to spring release new version to support Hibernate ORM 5.2?

Comment: You can read hibernate doc here. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/overview-summary.html

Comment: Try applyFlushModeHint Function.