# Which version of Spring Data Release Train supports Hibernate 5.2?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm developing a simple web app with Spring, JPA, Hibernate, all latest versions.

I've imported `hibernate-core` in `5.2.4.Final` as well as `spring-data-jpa` which version is set through the `Hopper-SR5` version of `spring-data-releasetrain`. But the spring related dependencies are still 4.2.x !!!

And I'm facing the `NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.getFlushMode()` problem related to the integration of Hibernate 5.2 into Spring which will be fixed in 4.3!
[Integrate Hibernate 5.2 with Spring framework 4.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37651837/integrate-hibernate-5-2-with-spring-framework-4-x)
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14334

Never noticed this page:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Hopper
=> Core: Upgrade Spring Framework baseline to **4.2**

So basically I suppose I'm not using the *correct* release train version (but it's the GA!)

But next release train doesn't have anything related to Spring Framework:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Ingalls
and the "next next" has Spring Framework 5:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Kay

What am I supposed to do?

- upgrade release train, to which version?
- keep release train to current version, but downgrade Hibernate version?
- remove release train and import each spring module one by one?

Thanks.

Comment: The baseline doesn't mean, it's the only Spring Version that is supported. It's the *minimum* version. Spring Data Hopper works perfectly fine with Spring 4.3

Comment: what do you mean @dunni ? how can I "fix" the Spring version? in my case, seems like it's ``spring-orm 4.2.8.RELEASE`` imported by ``spring-data-jpa 1.10.5.RELEASE``