# How to find compatible version pair of Hibernate + Spring-JPA? (Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, compatibility

SSCCE is here: https://github.com/dims12/TrySpringJpaPlusHibernate

I am trying to run Spring JPA without persistence.xml and have the following config:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@ImportResource("classpath:data_source.xml")
@EnableJpaRepositories("org.inthemoon.train.chinese.repositories")
public class BaseConfig {
   @Autowired
   private DataSource dataSource;

   @Bean
   public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
      LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean ans =
         new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
      ans.setDataSource(dataSource);
      ans.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
      ans.setPackagesToScan("org.inthemoon.train.chinese.data");
      return ans;
   }

   @Bean
   public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
      HibernateJpaVendorAdapter ans = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
      ans.setShowSql(false);
      ans.setGenerateDdl(true);
      ans.setDatabase(Database.H2);
      return ans;
   }

   @Bean
   public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
      JpaTransactionManager ans = new JpaTransactionManager();
      ans.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);

      return ans;
   }

}
```

it cause the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.getFlushMode()Lorg/hibernate/FlushMode;
...
```

P.S. Is there any way to configure `IoC` from the first attempt?

**UPDATE**

I am using following libs:

```
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.2.5.Final'

compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-jpa', version: '1.10.5.RELEASE'
```

**UPDATE 2**

I tried 8 different versions of `hibernate-core` to build with spring-jpa of `1.10.5.RELEASE`.

Versions from `5.2.1` to `5.2.6` were causing the same exception

```
NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.getFlushMode()Lorg/hibernate/FlushMode;
```

Versions `5.1.3` and `5.0.11` were causing

```
ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernateEntityManagerFactory
```

And the only version was causing something more complex was `5.2.0`. It was causing

```
SchemaManagementException: Attempt to resolve foreign key metadata from JDBC metadata failed to find column mappings for foreign key named [FKLOK22W31RKBMIIC2J96T9LTCN
```

The questions arose:

1) Does this mean that namely version `5.2.0` is compatible with `1.10.5`?

2) How would I know this without experiment?

3) Is this normal to guess versions this way? Wasn't the purpose of dependency management tools to avoid such things? If `spring-data-jpa:1.10.5` depends on hibernate of `5.2.0` then why doesn't this described in it's `POM`?

**UPDATE 3**

Out of the box example: https://github.com/dims12/TrySpringJpaPlusHibernate

It doesn't work.

Comment: Incompatible Version of JPA and Hibernate

Comment: @shazin how to find compatible pair?

Comment: It looks like hibernate 5.2.x is supported by the 1.10.x line of spring-data-jpa based on the pom file for spring-data-jpa: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/1.10.x/pom.xml

Comment: @LucasP then why it doesn't work?

Comment: Do you deploy your project in an application server, which maybe also provides hibernate libs with a different version? Or do you have other version conflicts? Can you post the output of `mvn dependency:tree`?

Comment: @dunni no I don't deploy to any server, it is standalone app. See SSCCE here https://github.com/dims12/TrySpringJpaPlusHibernate

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37651837/integrate-hibernate-5-2-with-spring-framework-4-x?noredirect=1&lq=1). Make sure to use Spring 4.3+ if you want to use Hibernate 5.2.

Comment: @manish how can I use Spring other than required by `spring-data-jpa`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spring Data JPA v1.10.6 depends on Spring v4.2 (v4.2.9 to be precise) and Spring v4.2 does not support Hibernate v5.2. Support for Hibernate v5.2 was added [only in Spring v4.3](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14334). Therefore, you must upgrade the Spring dependencies to v4.3.

---

Adding the following dependencies to the Gradle build file should work:

```
compile 'org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.4.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.4.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework:spring-context-support:4.3.4.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.4.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.3.4.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework:spring-orm:4.3.4.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework:spring-tx:4.3.4.RELEASE'
```

Your modified code [available on Github](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/41550583). Run Gradle tests as `gradle test` to verify that everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

usually when you have this Exception it means you should had ***hibernate-entitymanager*** to your porm. if you are using maven you can do it by adding this to your pom

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
   <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I also use to define my dataSource through a bean I do not inject it with autowired as you did I don't know if it works that way. I rather do like this

```
 @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gescable");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("root");
        return dataSource;
    }
```

Comment: `Autowired` is just because it is from separate config, technically it is a bean.

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested this versions in my project:

```
<hibernate.version>5.2.5.Final</hibernate.version>
<version>1.10.5.RELEASE</version>
```

and it worked for me.

my config file is like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "ge.shemo.repositories")
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class PersistenceConfig {

@Autowired
private Environment env;

@Value("${init-db:false}")
private String initDatabase;


@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    EntityManagerFactory factory = entityManagerFactory().getObject();
    return new JpaTransactionManager(factory);
}


@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(Boolean.FALSE);
    vendorAdapter.setShowSql(Boolean.FALSE);

    factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factory.setPackagesToScan("ge.shemo");

    Properties jpaProperties = getHibernateProperties();
    factory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    factory.setLoadTimeWeaver(new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver());
    return factory;
}

private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    /*prop.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");*/
    /*prop.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");*/
    //prop.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");
    // prop.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files","sql/import.sql");
    /*prop.put("hibernate.ejb.entitymanager_factory_name", "irakli");*/

    //prop.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    prop.put("hibernate.dialect", "ge.shemo.config.SQLServerUnicodeDialect");
    return prop;
}


@Bean
public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator() {
    return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
}


@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
    ds.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

    ds.setUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://LinkToDB:1433;useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=UTF-8;DatabaseName=Your_DB");
    ds.setUsername("USER");
    ds.setPassword("PASS");
    return ds;
}




@Bean
public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer(DataSource dataSource) {

    DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer = new     DataSourceInitializer();
    dataSourceInitializer.setDataSource(dataSource);
    ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
    //databasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("db.sql"));
    dataSourceInitializer.setDatabasePopulator(databasePopulator);
    dataSourceInitializer.setEnabled(Boolean.parseBoolean(initDatabase));
    return dataSourceInitializer;
}


@Bean
public AuditorAware<Long> createAuditorProvider() {
    return new SecurityAuditor();
}

@Bean
public AuditingEntityListener createAuditingListener() {
    return new AuditingEntityListener();
}



}
```

Comment: Have you tried to perform any operation with database?

Comment: I  changed version into my current project - where first step is authorization - then listing clients , client activities .... It was performing everything correctly - getting data from DB and writing updates back to SQL server.

Comment: I don't see any database manipulation code in your example. See my example: https://github.com/dims12/TrySpringJpaPlusHibernate

Comment: I'll try it now. At first glance only differance is that I use maven you use grandle. I'm downloading grandle and will try your code now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133085/discussion-between-irakli-and-dims).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem is a compatibility issue between `Spring Data JPA` and `Hibernate`. There seems to lack a synchronous explanation or @least version compatibility explanation between the guys @Spring ad the forks @Hibernate. For me, I have managed to make it work with the following versions

```
Spring Data JPA and Spring v5.0.0
1.10.0.RELEASE

and Hibernate 5.4.12.Final
```

Sometimes the issue arise when u forget to set the `setPackagesToScan()` `property` with your desired packages to be scanned in the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactorybean` but this is not the case. So yeah check out yr `Spring Data` and `Hibernate` versions! Cheers

Answer (score -1):

Do you need to include hibernate at all? Spring data-jpa includes all of the necessary hibernate components as far as I can see so I'm not sure why you need to add any extra hibernate dependencies

Comment: Without Hibernate I don't have any `javax.persistence` classes.

Comment: Spring Data JPA is not a JPA provider. It is a library/framework that adds an extra layer of abstraction on the top of a JPA provider (like Hibernate). So you also need a JPA implementation. Reference : [Dzone](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-the-difference-between-hibernate-and-sprin-1).