# Working with Java 8 Date/Time API in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, jsr310

I'm working with Java 8 Date/Time API (JSR-310) on a brand new Spring Boot (1.5) application. Prior the first public release we can stay on tip of every dependencies and that's why I want to clarify the state of JSR-310 handling on the complete Spring Boot stack.

## Boot Starter Web - Jackson serialization

Just add `jackson-datatype-jsr310` dependency.

But is this really necessary? If so, why is this not included in the standard bundle?

## Boot Starter Data - Hibernate persistence

This is where it gets tricky. I have struggling a bit with that, maybe because I'm using PostgreSQL.

Seems like Java 8 compatibility was added to JDBC for version 4.2, which means:

- Use a JDBC 4.2 driver (for PostgreSQL, current is 9.4.1212)
- Override Hibernate version >= 5.2.6, which brings support for JDBC 4.2

Related : [PSQLException - spring boot 1.4.1 - spring data jpa - offsetdatetime/localdatetime identified as Bytestream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40255521/4474898)

Everything works as expected, but as of current (Spring Boot 1.5.2) development status, am I doing OK, is there any preferred way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Regarding you first question: the jsr310 dependency is declared as [optional](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=jackson-datatype-jsr310) in [spring-boot-autoconfigure/pom.xml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/c64bc2accf6844e839c4459e2c6b29fccc8133f5/spring-boot-autoconfigure/pom.xml), meaning it's excluded by default unless you declare the dependency in your projet pom.xml.

I can give you a practical example that justifies its being optional. A few weeks ago, I migrated a Spring Boot project from Java 7 to Java 8. This project used the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), with a dependency on [jackson-datatype-joda](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-joda) API to manage temporal data. My project worked out of the box, without needing to migrate to the new java.time (jsr310) API beforehand. Afterwards I switched to the java.time API and replaced jackson-datatype-joda dependency with the jackson-datatype-jsr310 one. But in the mean time, I was able to work on some urgent issues than a non-required - though recommended - change of API.