# Date timezone with Spring boot and Jackson

Tags: java, spring, date, spring-boot, jackson

I'm developing a spring boot application that handles dates. When I submit an Appointment object that has a `startDateTime` and an `endDateTime` (Both are of type `java.util.Date`) I send a format like this:

```
{
    "lastName": "Jhon",
    "firstName": "Doe",
    "email": "jhon.doe@gmail.com",
    "description": "MyDescription",
    "startDateTime": "2017-10-09T22:43:07.109+0300",
    "endDateTime": "2017-10-09T21:40:07.109+0300",
}
```

When data is persisted in database it's with the correct timezone, when I try to retrieve my data back, they seem correct when I'm debugging however, once they are serialized by Jackson I have an output with these as value:

```
"startDateTime": "2017-10-09T19:43:07.109+0000",
"endDateTime": "2017-10-09T18:40:07.109+0000",
```

How can I configure Jackson to make usage of timezone that comes with the data from my repository?

------Update---------

I tried the answer with `OffsetDateTime` but the output is quite weird:

```
"startDateTime": {
        "offset": {
            "totalSeconds": 7200,
            "id": "+02:00",
            "rules": {
                "fixedOffset": true,
                "transitionRules": [],
                "transitions": []
            }
        },
        "month": "OCTOBER",
        "year": 2017,
        "hour": 21,
        "minute": 49,
        "nano": 654000000,
        "second": 15,
        "dayOfMonth": 9,
        "dayOfWeek": "MONDAY",
        "dayOfYear": 282,
        "monthValue": 10
    }
```

I would like to have something like:

> 2017-10-09T22:43:07.109+0300

Comment: use DateTime class which is more suitable for this case

Comment: Have you used the `JsonFormat` annotation if the `OffsetDateTime` fields (as it's in my answer below)?

Comment: Yes I added this annotation, but still didn't work

Comment: Then set `SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS` to false

Comment: And also register the `JavaTimeModule` to the `ObjectMapper` (it's not added by default, I guess)

Comment: I can't find JavaTimeModule class :/

Comment: It's in the java 8 module that I also mention in my answer: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8

Comment: I just added the dependencies, and it works like a charm. I was wondering if there's no configuration needed for the persistence part with hibernate. Anyway, thank you sir

Comment: Yes, you need additional configs for hibernate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718383/jpa-support-for-java-8-new-date-and-time-api - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46039236/7605325

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A `java.util.Date` [doesn't have any timezone information](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/). Once you deserialize a `String` to a `Date`, the offset `+0300` is lost: the date keeps just the timestamp value, and it can't know what's the original timezone it came from.

If the output must always be in `+03:00` offset, you can set it directly in the respective fields, using the `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat` annotation:

```
@JsonFormat(timezone = "GMT+03:00")
private Date startDateTime;

@JsonFormat(timezone = "GMT+03:00")
private Date endDateTime;
```

With this, the date fields will always be serialized to `+03:00` offset:

```
{
  "startDateTime":"2017-10-09T22:43:07.109+0300",
  "endDateTime":"2017-10-09T21:40:07.109+0300"
}
```

---

If the inputs can be in any other offset (not only `+03:00`) and you want to preserve it, the `java.util.Date` isn't the ideal type. One alternative is to use [Jackson Modules Java 8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8), if you're using Java >= 8.

*For Java 6 and 7, there's the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp) and the corresponding [Jackson module](https://github.com/lldata/jackson-datatype-threetenbp) - I haven't tested, though, but the code might be similar, as the ThreeTen Backport contains the same classes and methods, only the package is different - (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport is `org.threeten.bp`)*.

To preserve the date, time and offset, the best alternative is the `OffsetDateTime` class. So you just need to change the fields type and set the corresponding format to it:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXX")
private OffsetDateTime startDateTime;

@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXX")
private OffsetDateTime endDateTime;
```

In the object mapper, you must also register the `JavaTimeModule` and disable the [`ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE` feature](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE), so the offsets are preserved (the default behaviour is to convert to Jackson context's timezone, which might not be the same used in the inputs - by disabling this, the offset is preserved).

You can use a `JacksonConfigurator` (as [explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32842962/7605325)) and do these configurations:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
om.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
om.configure(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE, false);
```

This configuration is usually enough, but you can also set `SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS` to `false` as well, just in case.

---

If you still need to work with `java.util.Date`, you can use the API to convert from/to it. In Java 8, there's the new `Date.from` method:

```
// convert to java.util.Date
public Date getStartAsJavaUtilDate() {
    return Date.from(startDateTime.toInstant());
}
```

And in ThreeTen Backport, there's the `org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils` class:

```
// convert to java.util.Date
DateTimeUtils.toDate(startDateTime.toInstant());
```

To convert a `Date` back to `OffsetDateTime`, though, it's more tricky. The `Date` object has no timezone information, so it can't know the original offset. One alternative is to keep the original offset in a separate variable:

```
// keep the original offset
ZoneOffset startDateOffset = startDateTime.getOffset();
```

Then, you can convert the `Date` to `Instant`, and then convert it to the original offset:

```
// convert java.util.Date to original offset (Java 8)
startDateTime = date.toInstant().atOffset(startDateOffset);

// ThreeTen Backport
startDateTime = DateTimeUtils.toInstant(date).atOffset(startDateOffset);
```

Comment: how about spring.jackson.time-zone config? The annotation works for me while the spring config dose not.

Comment: `java.util.Date` comes with timezone info, somehow implicit. You actually sees it when logging it: `Sun Oct 28 02:00:00 CET 2018`.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using swagger with spring boot and your  Date is always getting serialised as long.  And SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS &  spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=false
are not helping below solution worked for me. Add it to your class annotated with @SpringBootApplication:

Issue: SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS value is not read from spring configuration file which need to be set false in order  to covert long value while serialisation.

```
@Autowired
private RequestMappingHandlerAdapter handlerAdapter;

@EventListener
public void handleContextRefresh(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    handlerAdapter
            .getMessageConverters()
            .stream()
            .forEach(c -> {
                if (c instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
                    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonMessageConverter = (MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) c;
                    ObjectMapper objectMapper = jsonMessageConverter.getObjectMapper();
                    objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
                }
            });
}
```