# How to create a new Date object without the year parameter in Java?

Tags: java, date, jsp, time, simpledateformat

I am trying to use new `SimpleDateFormat` to parse a string in the format dd-MM. Basically, I want to create a date object out of the string and persist in the database.

When I checked the database entry I see that it appends 1970 to the year column. I believe it is the default value of the year provided when it is empty. Is there a way to prevent the year value. I do not want to store information about the year.

My code -

```
String dateOfBirth = "14-Feb";
dbObject.save(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM").parse(dateOfBirth));
```

For the sake of simplicity, assume `dbObject.save()` the method expects a date object to be provided. I do not want to create a date of value - 14-Feb-1970, instead it should be just 14-Feb.

Comment: You're just looking for a different data structure. I'd save it as is (string), or create a custom 2-field class.

Comment: String pattern = "MM-dd";
     SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);

     String date = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
     System.out.println(date);   please find the code

Comment: @HasnainAliBohra The date variable is of type string. I am storing it as date object in db.

Comment: @ernest_k . cannot change the data structure unfortunately. The date column needs to be there as I am using Hibernate to store this in db

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Don’t use it. Also if you are using the `date` datatype of your database, there’s hardly a way to avoid also storing a year.

Comment: @OleV.V. What is the alternative for SimpleDateFormat ?

Comment: @BoudhayanDev The short answer is `DateTimeFormatter` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Use with the other classes from that API, it’s all so nice to work with. I think that Sweeper has given [a good and helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55888093/5772882).

Answer (score 6):

I would strongly suggest you use the [`java.time.MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html) class to store your dates. If your database doesn't support storing that, you can just store it as a string, and `parse` it when you get it out of the database.

Here is how you would parse your date:

```
MonthDay md = MonthDay.parse("14-Feb", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM").withLocale(Locale.US));
```

You can then store the string returned by `.toString` into the database (it will be something like `--02-14`), and the next time you `parse` it, you don't need a date time formatter:

```
MonthDay md = MonthDay.parse("--02-14");
```

Comment: Hi, is MonthDay compatible with Hibernate ? So I am using Spring+ Hibernate to store this value in database. The column is defined as Date ( SQL)

Comment: @BoudhayanDev See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46039236/5133585). It says it supports types like `LocalDate` and `LocalDateTime` but I don't know about `MonthDay`. Try it and see, I guess.

Comment: Looked into it.  Seems like LocalDate also adds a year if not provided

Comment: @BoudhayanDev Did you try `MonthDay`? Does it not work with hibernate?

Comment: Yes it does not work . I tried to change the hibernate column which was defined of type Date to MonthDate and it gave the following error - `The persistent field or property for a Temporal type must be of type java.util.Date, java.util.Calendar or java.util.GregorianCalendar`

Comment: @BoudhayanDev then I guess you can only store it as a string.

Comment: I cannot store it as string. Because, in spring boot repository, there are some sql queries running on this field which query the date column based on month criteria. I cannot apply these queries in the date column is changed to string

Comment: @BoudhayanDev I found [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/java-yearmonth-jpa-hibernate/), which tries to store a `YearMonth`. A `MonthDay` is kind of similar. Maybe that'll help? I am not familiar with hibernate so I'm afraid I can't help you much more.

Comment: There is no SQL-standard data type for a month-day. Trying to use the SQL `DATE` type is a misfit, a hack. I suggest instead that you store the month-day as text in a varchar column, using the standard ISO 8601 format seen in this Answer: `--MM-DD`. Notice that such text when sorted alphabetically is also chronological. In Java, such a string can be parsed and generated by the `MonthDay` class, as shown in this Answer.

Comment: So you are requiring that no year is stored, and at the same time requiring that you can use SQL queries that in turn require a full date (year, month and day of month). Obviously you cannot have that.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes that was the plan.

Comment: @BasilBourque Yes thanks. So, currently storing the day and month as separate values. As a result of that cannot use native SQL queries on them. So, have to move all the processing logic to Java layer. Hacky solution, but it works