# Failed to bind properties under 'logging.level.org.quartz' to org.springframework.boot.logging.LogLevel

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, quartz-scheduler

After migrating to the latest release of Spring Boot 2.2.1 from 2.1, my tests started to fail due to binding exceptions involving Quartz Scheduler logging (btw, using Java 8). I have defined the log levels in my app properties file in compliance with [Spring Boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-custom-log-levels), so I fail to see why the error is popping up. I am pretty sure there is some misconfiguration in the logging props or in the configuration class, since ALL the tests are failing on the same error, but simply cannot find it. Below are my error outputs and relevant files.

Error log from Intellij:

```java
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:40)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:80)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'logging.level.org.quartz' to org.springframework.boot.logging.LogLevel
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.handleBindError(Binder.java:364)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:324)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.lambda$null$1(Binder.java:412)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withSource(Binder.java:541)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.access$900(Binder.java:513)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.lambda$bindAggregate$2(Binder.java:413)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.AggregateElementBinder.bind(AggregateElementBinder.java:39)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.MapBinder$EntryBinder.lambda$bindEntries$0(MapBinder.java:157)
    at java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.MapBinder$EntryBinder.bindEntries(MapBinder.java:157)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.MapBinder.bindAggregate(MapBinder.java:68)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.AggregateBinder.bind(AggregateBinder.java:56)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.lambda$bindAggregate$3(Binder.java:415)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withIncreasedDepth(Binder.java:570)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.access$100(Binder.java:513)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindAggregate(Binder.java:415)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindObject(Binder.java:376)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:238)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:212)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.setLogLevels(LoggingApplicationListener.java:398)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeFinalLoggingLevels(LoggingApplicationListener.java:338)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:289)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:246)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:223)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:345)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [org.springframework.boot.logging.LogLevel] for value 'ON'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.springframework.boot.logging.LogLevel.ON
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:47)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:191)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindConverter$CompositeConversionService.convert(BindConverter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindConverter.convert(BindConverter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindConverter.convert(BindConverter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindProperty(Binder.java:435)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindObject(Binder.java:380)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:320)
    ... 78 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.springframework.boot.logging.LogLevel.ON
    at org.springframework.boot.convert.LenientObjectToEnumConverterFactory$LenientToEnumConverter.findEnum(LenientObjectToEnumConverterFactory.java:93)
    at org.springframework.boot.convert.LenientObjectToEnumConverterFactory$LenientToEnumConverter.convert(LenientObjectToEnumConverterFactory.java:80)
    at org.springframework.boot.convert.LenientObjectToEnumConverterFactory$LenientToEnumConverter.convert(LenientObjectToEnumConverterFactory.java:61)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService$ConverterFactoryAdapter.convert(GenericConversionService.java:436)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:41)
    ... 85 more
```

My root project pom.xml is :

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.company_name</groupId>
  <artifactId>project_name</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>project_name</name>
  <description>project_name</description>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <properties>
         <java.version>8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <modules>
     ...
    </modules>


  <build>
        <defaultGoal>package</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>
</project>
```

.. and pom.xml from the module on which tests are executed upon:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>company_project_name</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>app-web-api</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>app_name Web REST API</name>

    <!-- app_name DEPS -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company</groupId>
            <artifactId>company_project_name</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company</groupId>
            <artifactId>app_name-core</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company.app_name</groupId>
            <artifactId>app_name-web-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Spring Boot & Spring DEPS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Tomcat dependency -->
        <!--<dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope> </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-data</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSON utils DEPS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hppc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-json-org</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-afterburner</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- REST utils DEPS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.20</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Persistance DEPS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate5</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mattbertolini</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718383/jpa-support-for-java-8-new-date-and-time-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Uncomment in case that this error is reported by Tomcat: Error creating
            bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class] -->
        <!--<dependency> <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId> <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            </dependency> -->

        <!-- JDBC drivers DEPS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--Utilities DEPS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zeroturnaround</groupId>
            <artifactId>zt-exec</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Uncompressing lib -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Required for uncompressing 7z -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.tukaani</groupId>
            <artifactId>xz</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test DEPS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Added because of Java 9. For more info check https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-with-Java-9-and-above -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.23.1-GA</version>
        </dependency>

    <!--Added because <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId> was being reported missing-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
      <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

    <build>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <!-- <resources> <resource> <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes> <include>**/*.properties</include> <include>**/logback.xml</include>
            </includes> <excludes> <exclude>config/deprecated/*.properties</exclude>
            <exclude>config/*.properties</exclude> </excludes> <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource> <resource> <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <excludes> <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude> </excludes> </resource> <resource>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/generated-web-resources</directory>
            </resource> </resources> -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.company.MainApp</mainClass>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                    <profiles>dev,ng</profiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <configuration>
          <forkCount>0</forkCount>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

Application.properties:

```
# WARN|DEBUG|ERROR|FATAL|TRACE|INFO|OFF
logging.level.root=WARN
logging.level.org.springframework=WARN
logging.level.org.hibernate=WARN
logging.level.org.sejda=ERROR
logging.level.org.quartz=OFF
```

.. and my Quartz config class:

```
/**
 * Configuration of the Quartz scheduled.
 */
@Configuration
public class QuartzConfiguration {

  /**
   * Application's context.
   */
  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  /**
   * Creates {@link SpringBeanJobFactory} that adds auto-wiring to Quartz jobs.
   *
   * @return Created {@link SpringBeanJobFactory}.
   */
  @Bean
  public SpringBeanJobFactory springBeanJobFactory() {
    AutoWiringSpringBeanJobFactory jobFactory = new AutoWiringSpringBeanJobFactory();
    jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    return jobFactory;
  }

  /**
   * Creates {@link SchedulerFactoryBean} used by Quartz for scheduling.
   *
   * @return Created {@link SchedulerFactoryBean}.
   */
  @Bean
  public SchedulerFactoryBean scheduler(SpringBeanJobFactory jobFactory) {
    SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
    schedulerFactory.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true);
    schedulerFactory.setAutoStartup(true);
    schedulerFactory.setJobFactory(jobFactory);

    return schedulerFactory;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following two lines in the stack trace clearly say that `logging.level.org.quartz` is set to `ON` somewhere. Try checking your property files or IDE run configuration for this property. Enabling debug logging could help as well.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'logging.level.org.quartz' to org.springframework.boot.logging.LogLevel

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.springframework.boot.logging.LogLevel.ON
```

Comment: It is set in application-dev.properties, as it should be - `logging.level.org.quartz=ON`

Comment: I was so blinded by the exceptions that I didn't realize "ON" is not a valid logging level ..

Answer (score 0):

The valid options for debugging level are:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/api/index.html?org/springframework/boot/logging/LogLevel.html

ON is not a valid level.